# Induced almost complex structure of a complex structure

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $V$ be a complex vector space. A statement in Complex Geometry of Huybrechts p.25 is, that one could define an almost complex structure on the underlying real vector space of $V$ by $v \mapsto iv$.

If I get this right the underlaying real vector space of $V$, which I am going to call $W$, is the vector space one gets simply by taking all the vectors in $V$ and restricting the scalars to be in $\mathbb{R}$. Also if I get Huybrechts right, the idea of the definition of the almost complex structure is that every vector $v \in W$ is mapped to the vector one would get if multiplied with $i$ in the complex space $V$.

Now however I can't proof that this in fact is a linear mapping, which it should be in order to be an Endomorphism on $V$. My problem is that I'm not quite sure what a linear mapping between a complex vector space and a real vector space should be. Therefore my idea to understand this as a linear mapping

$$W \rightarrow V \overset{i}{\rightarrow} V \rightarrow W$$ fails in the last mapping $V \rightarrow W$.

I would be thankful for Your advice on what I am missing.

Comment: Write down a real basis for the vector space. Let $i$ act on these basis vectors, and write down the corresponding matrix. Have you tried this? For example take $\mathbb{C}$ with real basis $1=(1,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$. Then multiplying by $i$ takes $(0,1)\mapsto (-1,0)$ and $(1,0)\mapsto (0,1)$. Can you write down the matrix? How about in higher dimensions?

Comment: Well do I get you right, that I shouldn't see $v \mapsto iv$ as a scalar multiplication with i but instead see it as a mapping of basis vectors defining an endomorphism? This very well could be the solution to my problem.

Comment: Yes, that's how I think about it. That's how you get the embedding $\text{GL}(r,\mathbb{C})\subset\text{GL}(2r,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling the real vector space "$W$" is a bit confusing here. After all, it's still the same set! We just forget that there is a multiplication by $\mathbb C$, and only remember multiplication by $\mathbb R$. So let's keep the name $V$. Now we have to show that the map
$$V \to V, v \mapsto iv$$
is $\mathbb R$-linear. But as it is even $\mathbb C$-linear, and $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$, it is also $\mathbb R$-linear. Spelled out $\mathbb R$-linearity means
$$i(v+w) = iv + iw \quad \text{for} \quad v,w \in V$$
and
$$i(\lambda v) = \lambda(iv) \quad \text{for} \quad v \in  V, \lambda \in \mathbb R,$$
and both properties follow from the axioms of vector spaces and the commutativity of $\mathbb C$.